# How write benchmark statistics. How output from 'time' put into file

Tags: time, command-line

I have trouble with put 'time' output to file. 
When I use on linux console time program > file I get output no information from program time.

I need 3 digit time output, looks like on console

Comment: interesting. "time ls > output.txt" not working. &2 &1 etc too

Answer (score 0):

"time -o outputfile.txt command" gives you a full output:

> %Uuser %Ssystem %Eelapsed %PCPU (%Xtext+%Ddata %Mmax)k
>   %Iinputs+%Ooutputs (%Fmajor+%Rminor)pagefaults %Wswaps

If you add "-p" you get the three line output like in interactive console:

> ```
> real %e
> user %U
> sys %S
> ```

With:

> ```
>  Time
>
>    %E     Elapsed real time (in [hours:]minutes:seconds).
>
>    %e     (Not in tcsh.) Elapsed real time (in seconds).
>
>    %S     Total number of CPU-seconds that the  process  spent  in    kernel
>     mode.
>
>    %U     Total number of CPU-seconds that the process spent in user mode.
>
>    %P     Percentage of the CPU that this job got, computed as (%U + %S) /
>     %E.
>
>    Memory
>
>    %M     Maximum resident set size of the process during its lifetime, in
>     Kbytes.
>
>    %t     (Not in tcsh.) Average resident set  size    of  the  process,  in
>     Kbytes.
>
>    %K     Average  total  (data+stack+text)    memory use of the process, in
>     Kbytes.
>
>    %D     Average size of the process's unshared data area, in Kbytes.
>
>    %p     (Not in tcsh.) Average size  of  the  process's  unshared    stack
>     space, in Kbytes.
>
>    %X     Average size of the process's shared text space, in Kbytes.
>
>    %Z     (Not in tcsh.) System's page size, in bytes.  This is a per-sys-
>     tem constant, but varies between systems.
>
>    %F     Number of major page faults that occurred while the process  was
>     running.  These are faults where the page has to be read in from
>     disk.
>
>    %R     Number of minor, or recoverable, page faults.  These are    faults
>     for pages that are not valid but which have not yet been claimed
>     by other virtual pages.  Thus the data  in  the  page  is  still
>     valid but the system tables must be updated.
>
>    %W     Number of times the process was swapped out of main memory.
>
>    %c     Number  of  times the process was context-switched involuntarily
>     (because the time slice expired).
>
>    %w     Number of waits: times that  the    program  was  context-switched
>     voluntarily,  for instance while waiting for an I/O operation to
>     complete.
>
>    I/O
>
>    %I     Number of file system inputs by the process.
>
>    %O     Number of file system outputs by the process.
>
>    %r     Number of socket messages received by the process.
>
>    %s     Number of socket messages sent by the process.
>
>    %k     Number of signals delivered to the process.
>
>    %C     (Not in tcsh.) Name and command line arguments  of  the  command
>     being timed.
>
>    %x     (Not in tcsh.) Exit status of the command.
> ```

source: man time :)

Comment: but only 2 digit precision. if You run in normal mode You get 3. soory this is not answer

Comment: You can find the answer here, then:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70653/increase-e-precision-with-usr-bin-time-shell-command